# ReactNative app crashing when using @gorhom/bottom-sheet

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet, nx-monorepo

We have a Nx monorepo workspace with React web app and ReactNative mobile app setup.

We are trying to using `@gorhom/bottom-sheet` but as soon as we are presenting bottomsheet the mobile app is crashing with the below error -

```
ERROR  Error: Trying to convert a cyclic object to a shareable. This is not supported.

This error is located at:
    in GestureDetector (created by BottomSheetDraggableViewComponent)
    in BottomSheetDraggableViewComponent (created by BottomSheet)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent(View))
    in AnimatedComponent(View)
    in Unknown (created by BottomSheet)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent(View))
    in AnimatedComponent(View)
    in Unknown (created by BottomSheet)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by BottomSheetContainerComponent)
    in BottomSheetContainerComponent (created by BottomSheet)
    in BottomSheetGestureHandlersProvider (created by BottomSheet)
    in BottomSheet (created by BottomSheet)
    in PortalHostComponent (created by PortalProviderComponent)
    in PortalProviderComponent (created by BottomSheetModalProviderWrapper)
    in BottomSheetModalProviderWrapper (created by Settings)
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by Settings)
    in Settings (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen
    in Unknown (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by StackNav)
    in StackNav (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in MobileApp(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

This is a sample code we are using from the documentation -

```
import React, { useCallback, useMemo, useRef } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native'
import { BottomSheetModal, BottomSheetModalProvider } from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet'
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

const Settings = () => {
    // ref
    const bottomSheetModalRef = useRef<BottomSheetModal>(null)

    // variables
    const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ['25%', '50%'], [])

    // callbacks
    const handlePresentModalPress = useCallback(() => {
        bottomSheetModalRef.current?.present()
    }, [])
    const handleSheetChanges = useCallback((index: number) => {
        console.log('handleSheetChanges', index)
    }, [])

    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <BottomSheetModalProvider>
                <View>
                    <Text>Settings</Text>
                    <View>
                        <Button onPress={handlePresentModalPress} title='Present Modal' color='black' />
                        <BottomSheetModal
                            ref={bottomSheetModalRef}
                            index={1}
                            snapPoints={snapPoints}
                            onChange={handleSheetChanges}
                        >
                            <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
                                <Text>Awesome </Text>
                            </View>
                        </BottomSheetModal>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </BottomSheetModalProvider>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    )
}

export default Settings

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 24,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'grey',
    },
    contentContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
})
```

This is our package.json

```
{   
    "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
        "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.11.3",
        "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.11.3",
        "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.11.3",
        "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.11.3",
        "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.11.2",
        "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.11.3",
        "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "v5.0.0-alpha.3",
        "@mui/material": "^5.14.0",
        "@notifee/react-native": "^7.8.0",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.0",
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.12",
        "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.11.2",
        "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.0.0",
        "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.7",
        "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.3.2",
        "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^17.3.2",
        "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^17.4.2",
        "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.8",
        "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
        "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
        "@sentry/browser": "^7.51.2",
        "@swc/helpers": "~0.5.0",
        "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^4.3.0",
        "@transifex/cli": "^5.3.0",
        "@transifex/native": "^5.3.0",
        "@transifex/react": "^5.3.0",
        "ag-grid-enterprise": "^29.3.4",
        "ag-grid-react": "^29.3.4",
        "axios": "1.1.3",
        "bowser": "^2.11.0",
        "classnames": "^2.3.2",
        "docx-preview": "^0.1.15",
        "docx-templates": "^4.11.1",
        "firebase": "^9.22.0",
        "github-markdown-css": "^5.2.0",
        "gleap": "^10.0.5",
        "humanize-plus": "^1.8.2",
        "imask": "^6.6.1",
        "immer": "^9.0.1",
        "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
        "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.30",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "lottie-react-native": "^5.1.6",
        "mathjs": "^11.8.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
        "papaparse": "^5.4.1",
        "polished": "^4.2.2",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-country-flag": "^3.1.0",
        "react-custom-scrollbars-2": "^4.5.0",
        "react-dnd": "^16.0.1",
        "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^16.0.1",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0",
        "react-excel-renderer": "^1.1.0",
        "react-imask": "^6.6.1",
        "react-is": "18.2.0",
        "react-loading-skeleton": "^3.3.1",
        "react-markdown": "^8.0.7",
        "react-medium-image-zoom": "^5.1.6",
        "react-native": "0.72.3",
        "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
        "react-native-calendars": "^1.1294.0",
        "react-native-code-push": "^8.0.1",
        "react-native-document-picker": "^8.1.4",
        "react-native-flipper": "^0.184.0",
        "react-native-floating-action": "^1.22.0",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
        "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.8.0",
        "react-native-gleapsdk": "^9.0.4",
        "react-native-image-picker": "^5.3.1",
        "react-native-keyboard-accessory": "^0.1.16",
        "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
        "react-native-mask-input": "^1.2.3",
        "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^14.0.1",
        "react-native-orientation-locker": "^1.5.0",
        "react-native-paper": "^5.4.1",
        "react-native-pell-rich-editor": "^1.9.0",
        "react-native-plotly": "^6.0.0",
        "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^3.3.0",
        "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
        "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
        "react-native-shake": "github:vinaythakurcn/react-native-shake",
        "react-native-skeleton-placeholder": "^5.2.4",
        "react-native-svg-flagkit": "^0.9.5",
        "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.6",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
        "react-native-walkthrough-tooltip": "github:vinaythakurcn/react-native-walkthrough-tooltip",
        "react-native-webview": "^11.26.1",
        "react-native-wheel-color-picker": "^1.2.0",
        "react-pdf": "^6.2.2",
        "react-plotly.js": "^2.6.0",
        "react-popper": "^2.3.0",
        "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
        "react-responsive-modal": "^6.4.1",
        "react-style-proptype": "^3.2.2",
        "react-toastify": "^9.1.2",
        "react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
        "react-use": "^17.4.0",
        "redux-flipper": "^2.0.2",
        "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
        "redux-sentry-middleware": "^0.2.2",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
        "rehype-katex": "^6.0.3",
        "remark-gfm": "^3.0.1",
        "remark-math": "^5.1.1",
        "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
        "sanitize-html": "^2.10.0",
        "sparser": "^1.4.12",
        "striptags": "^3.2.0",
        "styled-components": "5.3.6",
        "tslib": "^2.3.0",
        "use-debounce": "^9.0.4",
        "uuid": "^9.0.0",
        "zod": "^3.21.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.14.5",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
        "@commitlint/cli": "^17.0.0",
        "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.0.0",
        "@jscutlery/semver": "^3.0.0",
        "@nx/cypress": "16.1.4",
        "@nx/detox": "16.7.1",
        "@nx/eslint-plugin": "16.1.4",
        "@nx/jest": "16.7.1",
        "@nx/js": "16.7.1",
        "@nx/linter": "16.1.4",
        "@nx/react": "16.1.4",
        "@nx/react-native": "^16.7.1",
        "@nx/storybook": "^16.4.0",
        "@nx/web": "16.4.0",
        "@nx/webpack": "16.1.4",
        "@nx/workspace": "16.1.4",
        "@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs": "^1.0.3",
        "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.10",
        "@react-native-community/cli": "11.3.5",
        "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "11.3.5",
        "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "11.3.5",
        "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.9",
        "@storybook/addon-essentials": "7.0.23",
        "@storybook/addon-jest": "^7.0.24",
        "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.24",
        "@storybook/addon-ondevice-actions": "^6.5.3",
        "@storybook/addon-ondevice-backgrounds": "^6.5.3",
        "@storybook/addon-ondevice-controls": "^6.5.3",
        "@storybook/addon-ondevice-notes": "^6.5.3",
        "@storybook/core-common": "^7.0.9",
        "@storybook/core-server": "7.0.23",
        "@storybook/react": "^7.0.10",
        "@storybook/react-native": "^6.5.3",
        "@storybook/react-vite": "7.0.23",
        "@storybook/testing-react": "^2.0.0",
        "@svgr/webpack": "^6.1.2",
        "@swc/cli": "~0.1.62",
        "@swc/core": "~1.3.51",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-native": "5.4.2",
        "@testing-library/react": "14.0.0",
        "@testing-library/react-native": "12.1.2",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
        "@types/humanize-plus": "^1.8.0",
        "@types/jest": "^29.5.3",
        "@types/node": "18.14.4",
        "@types/papaparse": "^5.3.7",
        "@types/react": "18.0.28",
        "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
        "@types/react-is": "17.0.3",
        "@types/react-native": "0.72.2",
        "@types/redux-mock-store": "^1.0.3",
        "@types/redux-sentry-middleware": "^0.2.2",
        "@types/styled-components": "5.1.26",
        "@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.2.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.58.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.58.0",
        "@welldone-software/why-did-you-render": "^7.0.1",
        "abortcontroller-polyfill": "^1.7.5",
        "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.21.4",
        "babel-jest": "^29.6.1",
        "babel-plugin-styled-components": "1.10.7",
        "commitizen": "^4.3.0",
        "cypress": "^12.11.0",
        "cz-conventional-changelog": "^3.3.0",
        "detox": "^20.11.1",
        "eslint": "~8.15.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.7.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "7.32.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0",
        "genversion": "^3.1.1",
        "husky": "^8.0.3",
        "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
        "javascript-obfuscator": "^4.0.2",
        "jest": "^29.6.1",
        "jest-circus": "^29.4.1",
        "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.6.1",
        "jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.3",
        "jest-react-native": "18.0.0",
        "jest-styled-components": "^7.1.1",
        "lint-staged": "^13.2.2",
        "metro": "0.76.7",
        "metro-babel-register": "0.76.7",
        "metro-config": "0.76.7",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.7",
        "metro-react-native-babel-transformer": "0.76.7",
        "metro-resolver": "0.76.7",
        "msw": "^1.2.1",
        "node-fetch": "^2.6.12",
        "nx": "16.1.4",
        "nx-cloud": "latest",
        "prettier": "^2.6.2",
        "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
        "react-native-svg-transformer": "1.0.0",
        "react-refresh": "^0.10.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
        "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
        "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
        "ts-node": "10.9.1",
        "typescript": "~5.0.2",
        "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
        "vite": "^4.3.4",
        "webpack-merge": "^5.9.0",
        "webpack-obfuscator": "^3.5.1"
    },
    "lint-staged": {
        "packages/**/src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": "eslint --cache --fix",
        "packages/**/src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css,md}": "prettier --write"
    },
    "config": {
        "commitizen": {
            "path": "./node_modules/cz-conventional-changelog"
        }
    },
    "overrides": {
        "@storybook/addon-actions": "7.0.23",
        "@storybook/addon-controls": "7.0.23"
    }
}
```

I have also tried `@gorhom/bottom-sheet@4.4.7` but the same is happening.

Answer (score 0):

i do use this package, try to adapt this to your case, hope this helps.

My component:

```
import React, { useCallback, useMemo, useRef, memo, useState } from 'react';
import BottomSheet from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { ch, cw } from '../../utils/DimensionsStyles';
import { ThemeConfig } from 'tailwindcss/types/config';
import { theme } from '../../../tailwind.config';
import useBottomSheetStore from '../../stores/bottomSheet';

type BottomSheetProps = {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
};

const { colors } = theme?.extend as ThemeConfig;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  line: {
    width: cw(75),
    height: ch(4),
    backgroundColor: colors['primary'],
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: ch(15),
    marginBottom: ch(25),
    borderRadius: 2,
  },
});

const CustomBottomSheet = ({ children }: BottomSheetProps) => {
  const { bottomSheet, setBottomSheet } = useBottomSheetStore(state => state);
  const [bottomSpace, setBottomSpace] = useState(0);

  const MAX_TRANSLATE_Y =
    Platform.OS === 'ios'
      ? bottomSheet.height?.ios + '%'
      : bottomSheet.height?.android + '%';

  const snapPoints = useMemo(
    () => [
      '10%',
      '20%',
      '30%',
      '40%',
      '50%',
      '60%',
      '70%',
      '80%',
      '90%',
      '100%',
    ],
    [],
  );

  const handleComponent = () => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity testID="top-line-button" onPress={handleMove}>
        <View style={styles.line} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  const sheetRef = useRef<any>(null);

  const handleMove = () => {
    if (bottomSheet.indexBottomSheet > 1) {
      sheetRef.current?.collapse();

      setBottomSheet({
        ...bottomSheet,
        showBottomSheet: false,
        indexBottomSheet: 1,
        zIndex: -1,
      });

      switch (bottomSheet.component) {
        case 'Daily':
          Platform.OS === 'ios' ? setBottomSpace(20) : setBottomSpace(4);
          break;
        case 'Monthly':
          Platform.OS === 'ios' ? setBottomSpace(34) : setBottomSpace(38);

          break;
        case 'Range':
          Platform.OS === 'ios' ? setBottomSpace(0) : setBottomSpace(-20);

          break;
      }
    } else {
      sheetRef.current?.expand();
      setBottomSheet({
        ...bottomSheet,
        showBottomSheet: true,
        indexBottomSheet: 9,
        zIndex: 1,
      });
      setBottomSpace(0);
    }
  };

  const handleSheetChange = useCallback(index => {
    setBottomSheet({
      ...bottomSheet,
      indexBottomSheet: index,
      showBottomSheet: index > 0 ? true : false,
      zIndex: index > 0 ? 1 : -1,
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '100%',
        bottom: ch(bottomSpace),
        height: MAX_TRANSLATE_Y,
        zIndex: bottomSheet.zIndex,
      }}
      testID="bottom-sheet"
    >
      <BottomSheet
        ref={sheetRef}
        index={bottomSheet.indexBottomSheet}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        overDragResistanceFactor={0}
        handleComponent={handleComponent}
        onChange={handleSheetChange}
        backgroundStyle={{ borderRadius: 0 }}
      >
        {children}
      </BottomSheet>
    </View>
  );
};

export default memo(CustomBottomSheet);
```

My utils Dimensions:

```
  import {
  widthPercentageToDP as wp,
  heightPercentageToDP as hp,
} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';

const layoutScreenWidth = 375;
const layoutScreenHeight = 812;

export const cw = (pixels: number) => {
  const proportion = (pixels / layoutScreenWidth) * 100;
  return wp(proportion);
};

export const ch = (pixels: number) => {
  const proportion = (pixels / layoutScreenHeight) * 100;
  return hp(proportion);
};
```

My store with zustand:

```
 import { create } from 'zustand';

export type BottomSheet = {
  showBottomSheet: boolean;
  component: string;
  indexBottomSheet: number;
  height?: {
    ios?: number;
    android?: number;
  };
  zIndex?: number;
};

export type BottomSheetState = {
  bottomSheet: BottomSheet;
  setBottomSheet: ({
    showBottomSheet,
    indexBottomSheet,
    component,
    height,
    zIndex,
  }: BottomSheet) => void;
  resetBottomSheet: () => void;
};

const useBottomSheetStore = create<BottomSheetState>()(set => ({
  bottomSheet: {
    showBottomSheet: false,
    component: 'Monthly',
    indexBottomSheet: 0,
    height: {
      ios: 65,
      android: 55,
    },
    zIndex: -1,
  } as BottomSheet,

  setBottomSheet: (bottomSheet: BottomSheet) =>
    set((state: BottomSheetState) => ({
      bottomSheet: {
        ...state.bottomSheet,
        ...bottomSheet,
      },
    })),
  resetBottomSheet: () =>
    set(() => ({
      bottomSheet: {
        showBottomSheet: false,
        component: 'Monthly',
        indexBottomSheet: 0,
        height: {
          ios: 65,
          android: 55,
        },
        zIndex: -1,
      },
    })),
}));

export default useBottomSheetStore;
```

[image]

Comment: is this in Nx monorepo? I mean your reactnative app is in Nx? Actually I have used `@gorhom/bottom-sheet` in my other projects a lot but they were plain RN projects. I believe this issue is specifically happening when using in Nx.

Comment: Hello no this is not a NX repo, it’s a normal RN project

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this issue @VinayThakur? I am facing the same obstacle within a NX repo.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same issue but I had a bare React Native repository.

Try to downgrade `react-native-reanimated` from `3.3.0` to version `^2` by running:

`yarn upgrade react-native-reanimated@^2`

Don't forget to install the pods again if you have a project using cocoapods.
I also reset Metro cache by running `yarn start --reset-cache`